# Copy one HashMap<K,V> to another HashMap<V,K> in O(1) complexity (JAVA)

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, hashmap, time-complexity

Suppose I have a `HashMap<String,String>` which have elements `{one=1, two=2, three=3, four=4}` and I want to create another `HashMap<String,String>` whose elements would be `{1=one, 2=two, 3=three, 4=four}`

One approach is

```
HashMap<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();

map1.put("one",1);
map1.put("two",2);
map1.put("three",3);
map1.put("four",4);

HashMap<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>();

  for(String s : map.keySet())
  {
    map2.put(map.get(s),s);
  }
```

But it has time complexity **O(N)**

I want to know is there any way to do this in **O(1)**

Comment: In what universe could copying N values *ever* be only _O(1)_? By the very nature of what you're doing, it **cannot** be less than _O(N)_.

Comment: @Andreas Maybe OP wants to know if there exists a bidirectional map structure, that's my guess. @Daniel check Guava's [`BiMap`](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-bimap)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be after a bidirectional map. Java does not have such datastructure in its core library.

But [Google Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) has [`BiMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/), which seems to be what you want:

```
BiMap<String, String> biMap = HashBiMap.create();

biMap.put("key1", "value1");
biMap.put("key2", "value2");

BiMap<String, String> inverse = biMap.inverse();

String key1 = inverse.get("value1"); // key1
```

Here the `BiMap.inverse()` method returns a *view* of the original map. This is a `O(1)` time complexity operation.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with [@andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas), it isn't possible with *HashMap*.

You might want to use BitMap as suggested by [@fps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1876620/fps) but if have to do it with *HashMap* you don't really have many options.

Here is how to invert a *HashMap* with streams API:

```
Map<String,String> map = Map.of("one","1","two","2","three","3")

Map<String,String> reversedMap = map.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .map(es -> Map.entry(es.getValue(),es.getKey()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(es -> es.getKey(), es->es.getValue()));
```